# how to call a remote java class(method)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a java based software and my client wants to load some data to the software using a different tool. I need to write a java module that can speak with both and acts as a mediator. How do I pass inputs from 3rd party tool to the my java based software?

If I could invoke any class(in java based software) from eclipse using the remote invocation then it would suffice my need.

I have never worked on remote invocation.

Comment: There is a framework called Akka that might help you.

Comment: can you describe your current architecture and explain your problem clearly

Comment: This is pretty broad. Depending on your needs, you could use files, a database, JMS, REST, RMI, Akka, Apache Thrift, etc. That said, if you just want to call a Java method in another Java program, and you are not going to consider any other solution, then Java RMI is your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could look into using [Java RMI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index-jsp-136424.html).

However, this is usually done with Web Service http calls now.

I think most people would recommend using a [RESTful](http://www.andrewhavens.com/posts/20/beginners-guide-to-creating-a-rest-api/) solution and passing [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) representations of your objects back and forth between the two distributed systems.